# How to implement a time interval as an exponential function?

Tags: time, simulation, distribution, intervals, exponential

I need to implement an event (stock loss error) that occurs between time intervals as a renewal process. With every day of non-occurrence the probability of occurrence at the other day increases based on an exponential distribution: "The time intervals are based on an exponential distribution with a mean time between stock loss events (TBSLE). The frequency of (stock loss-)occurrence is the reciprocal of TBSLE. The expected value for the mean stock loss quantity can be estimated as 2.05."
First try:

```
def stockLossError(self):
    stockLossErrorProbability = 0
    inverseLambda = 
    errors = 0

randomnumber = np.random.exponential(scale=inverseLambda,size=(1,1))
  if(randomnumber > stockLossErrorProbability):
    self.daysSinceLastError += 1
    self.errors += 2.05
```

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you tell us what time advance mechanism you're using in your simulation.  You can get entirely different implementations and entirely different results depending on whether you use fixed increment (delta-t) or next-event for the time advance.  See [this paper by AlRowaei](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6147952&tag=1) for details.

Comment: The simulation uses the Discrete Time Approach. Once a day (delta-t) the simulation should check if a event occurs.  
The event again should occur between time intervals which are based on an exponential distribution.